# Property of a JS dom object overwritten by a sub-object in the DOM tree?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, properties

In an HTML code , i have a form Tag :

```
<form id='my_form' action='url.hmtl'> ... </form>
```

The corresponding JS object has a property named 'action', which contains the string 'url.html':

```
my_form=document.getElementById('my_form');
console.log(form.action);
```

The above code displays: url.hmtl
But if i add a sub-object, say an input, inside the form, with id='action':

```
<form id='my_form' action='url.hmtl'>
  <input type="hidden" id="action" />
</form>
```

Then form.action is now the JS object corresponding to the input.

My questions :

1. Is this behaviour normal ?
2. Should  I forbid myself to use the string 'action' as id of any input ?
3. If there is such an input, is there any way to get the original property 'Action' of the form or is it lost for ever ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a default behaviour, and will happen everytime you do somethink like that. You can use the getAttribute() function to get the Attribute.

```
my_form=document.getElementById('my_form');
console.log(form.getAttribute("action");
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is this behaviour normal?

[Yes, unfortunately](http://jibbering.com/faq/names/).

> Should I forbid myself to use the string 'action' as id of any input?

Yes, that one [and many more](http://jibbering.com/faq/names/unsafe_names.html).

> If there is such an input, is there any way to get the original property 'Action' of the form or is it lost for ever?

The attribute is still in the DOM, and when you remove the input the `action` property would represent the attribute's value again. Until then, you can use the [`getAttribute` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute) of the form element.

Answer (score 1):

The form attribute "action" is not overwritten. See example of Florian.

The question is if you experiencing a problem when sending the form to the "action" address ?
A mistake in the URL might cause an unwanted result (triggered by your typo "url.hmtl" instead of " url.html"

To answer your questions:

1. The behaviour is normal but perhaps confusing because it differs if you address an element by id or get the value of an attribute.
2. there is no need to avoid using "action" as id as long as you are specific enough about the information you are interested in. (form attribute or input element)
3. the form attribute action is not lost as properly answered by Florian :-)